# number represented as E in spite of using scipen in R

Tags: r, rstudio, scientific-notation

I have a number like '102622812'. I have used scipen as follows

```
options(scipen=999)
```

But When I write the number to a file using write.csv, I still get it in a format like 1.03E+08

I have also tried converting this column to character type and writing to the file. I still get the same problem.

Comment: How did you check the value in the .csv file? From the capital `E` I suppose Excel, and if so it's because Excel is displaying in scientific format.

Comment: @Molx, you're right. From R, it was a number, Excel was converting it to scientific notation. Thanks!

Comment: This is worth posting as an answer. I imagine it happens to more than a few people, even if it seems rather elementry. SO is for beginners too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the .csv file is saved without scientific notation, spreadsheet software like Excel will display them in scientific notation. Some options to check the real output are:

- Open the file in a simple text editor, like Notepad or Gedit
- Use `readLines("file.csv")` on R.
- Print the file contents in terminal (`type file.csv` on Windows, `cat file.csv` on Linux/Mac).